# can sql alias can use for both column and table at the same time?

Tags: sql

i tried it but it not works
how to implement it??
thanks

eg.

`Select a as columnA From TableB as b Where b.a= 'test'`

Would some one suggest how to realize this sql query
or how to modify it

Comment: Can you explain in what way it does not work?

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused as to exactly what you are looking for, but based on your code example you may want to say:

```
SELECT a AS columnA 
  FROM TableB b 
 WHERE b.a = 'test'
```

Which would allow you to query `a` using table alias `b`.

Comment: I think the `AS` is optional. Is there another difference I don't see?

Comment: not works
try this:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_tryit.asp

SELECT A as CompanyName 
FROM customers B
Where B.A='Alfreds Futterkiste'

Comment: You don't use the `AS` keyword for the table alias.

Comment: thx but i tried SELECT A as CompanyName FROM customers B Where B.A='Alfreds Futterkiste'  it still fail

Comment: What database are you using? What error did you get? Can you include the error text in your question?

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what problem you are getting.
 i tried this and its working fine for me.

here is the sql query and demo table

```
SELECT VoteTypeId AS  vcol
  FROM VoteType v 
 WHERE v.VoteTypeId = 4
```

and table structure is

```
VoteTypeId  VoteType
----------- --------------------------------------------------
1           Yes/No
2           Multiple Choice
4           Qualitative
```

Comment: some problem with formating in my reply. tha table structure us first value is for voteTypeId Column

Comment: SELECT VoteTypeId AS  vcol is not working
i am using innodb, thanks

Comment: it said unknown Unknown column  in 'where clause'

Comment: for sure i don't get this column in my database but i change the name

Comment: i have use these statements in sql server 2005